# banner ads not visible in html page

Tags: javascript, banner-ads

i have a file banners.js

```
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.attachEvent)
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.addEventListener)
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

var nextAd;

function makeBannerAds() {
    var bannerBox = document.createElement("div");
    bannerBox.id = "bannerBox";
    document.body.appendChild(bannerBox);
    for (var i=0; i<adsURL.length; i++) {
        var bannerAd = document.createElement("div");
        bannerAd.className = "bannerAd";
        bannerAd.style.zIndex = i;
        var urlLink = document.createElement("a");
        urlLink.href = adsURL[i];
        var bannerIndex = document.createElement("img");
        bannerIndex.src = "banner" + i +".jpg";
        bannerIndex.style.width="290px";
        bannerIndex.style.height="55px";
        bannerBox.appendChild(bannerAd);
    }
    bannerBox.appendChild(bannerAd);
    setInterval("changeBannerAd()", 10000);
}

function changeBannerAd() {
    var allAds = document.getElementById("bannerBox").childNodes;
    alert('work');
    for(var i=0; i<num; i++) {
        if(allAds.style.zIndex == 0) {
            allAds.style.top = "-50px";
            nextAd = allAds;
        }
    }

    for(var i=0; i<num; i++) {
        allAds.style.zIndex--;

        if(allAds.style.zIndex < 0)
            allAds.style.zIndex = num-1;
    }

    var timeDelay = 0;
    for(var i=-50; i<=0; i++) {
        setTimeout("moveNextAd(" + i + ")", timeDelay);
        timeDelay += 15;
    }
}

function moveNextAd(top) {
    nextAd.style.top = top + ".px" 
}

addEvent(window, "load", makeBannerAds(), false);
```

the second file
ads.js

```
var adsURL = new Array();

//this stores each item in the array using a index place holder
adsURL[0] = "testpage0.htm";
adsURL[1] = "testpage1.htm";
adsURL[2] = "testpage2.htm";
adsURL[3] = "testpage3.htm";
adsURL[4] = "testpage4.htm";
adsURL[5] = "testpage5.htm";
adsURL[6] = "testpage6.htm";
adsURL[7] = "testpage7.htm";
adsURL[8] = "testpage8.htm";
adsURL[9] = "testpage9.htm";
adsURL[10] = "testpage10.htm";
adsURL[11] = "testpage11.htm";
//and an html file where these are included.
```

javascript is not showing any error and also all the statements are running but the images are not visible on the page. i couldnot figure the problem. working from last 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer:

Some of your code had to be revised I think. I just edited this off of what I thought it was supposed to look like.

Check the new **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5R3rz/14/)** 
I think it might be getting you closer.

Briefly, the issue was that `childNodes()` returns an array of elements, so you need to reference that variable as you would an array

Secondly, you didn't have all the appends that were required.

```
var adsURL = new Array();
adsURL[0] = "testpage0.htm";
...
adsURL[11] = "testpage11.htm";

var nextAd;

var moveNextAd = function (top) {
    nextAd.style.top = top + ".px"
}; //changed this to function as variable, answer explained below

var changeBannerAd = function () {
    var num = adsURL.length
    var allAds = document.getElementById("bannerBox")
    allAds = allAds.childNodes;
    //^^^ here is what was wrong
    // Child nodes returns an array of elements
    // So for allAds, you should reference it with allAds[i]
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (allAds[i].style.zIndex == 0) {
            allAds[i].style.top = "-50px";
            nextAd = allAds[i++];
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        allAds[i].style.zIndex--;

        if (allAds[i].style.zIndex < 0) allAds[i].style.zIndex = num - 1;
    }

    var timeDelay = 0;
    for (var i = -50; i <= 0; i++) {
        setTimeout((function () {
            moveNextAd(" + i + ");
        }()), timeDelay);
        timeDelay += 15;
    }
}; //changed this to function as variable too.

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.attachEvent) object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.addEventListener) object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

function makeBannerAds() {
    var bannerBox = document.createElement("div");
    bannerBox.id = "bannerBox";
    document.body.appendChild(bannerBox);
    for (var i = 0; i < adsURL.length; i++) {
        var bannerAd = document.createElement("div");
        bannerAd.className = "bannerAd";
        bannerAd.style.zIndex = i;
        bannerAd.style.position = "absolute";
        var urlLink = document.createElement("a");
        urlLink.href = adsURL[i];
        var bannerIndex = document.createElement("img");
        bannerIndex.src = "banner" + i + ".jpg";
        bannerIndex.style.width = "290px";
        bannerIndex.style.height = "55px";
        urlLink.appendChild(bannerIndex); //Here is the other problem
        bannerAd.appendChild(urlLink); //All these weren't appended
        bannerBox.appendChild(bannerAd); // to each other
    }
    setInterval((function () {
        changeBannerAd();
    }()), 10000);
}

addEvent(window, "load", makeBannerAds(), false);
```

Secondly, not to be picky or anything but you should probably declare the functions you pass into `setInterval` or `setTimeout` as variables rather than explicit functions or run them through an anonymous function like I have done. These two functions use a form of eval, and as we all know [eval is evil](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil), and [eval is evil](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

### Old answer; ignore

**Question**: Is your ads.js added before or after banners.js
Try adding the script tag before banners.js
I just placed the `ads.js` content above the `banners.js` script in a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5R3rz/2/)** and it worked just fine for me

Check the JS Fiddle for full code at the top.

Comment: thanks for your help now there is only one problem in
nextAd.style.top = top + "px"; it produces an error
cannot read property style of undefined

Comment: thanks alot for your help. there aere a couple of syntax errors . but this code helped me alot. thanks again